# Is there a text that axiomatizes general relativity in first-order logic?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations

I have read some texts that axiomatize special relativity in first-order logic, but I haven't yet found any for general relativity. Can someone direct me to such a text?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for: H. Andréka, I. Németi, J. X. Madarász, G. Székely, *"On Logical Analysis of Relativity Theories"*, [arXiv:1105.0885](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0885)?

Comment: I hope this is just a placeholder for a more complete answer. Link-only answers [are not good in the long term](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/226705).

Comment: @Ruslan: I am aware of, and I largely agree with, most of the  standard arguments against link-only answers. I don't believe those arguments apply here.   Linkrot is not likely to be a problem when the link is to the arxiv.   Also, this is not just a link to a source in which the answer to the question is buried; instead it is a link to a source which is, in its entirety, exactly what I believe the OP is looking for.  Finally, it's not clear that the OP could have found this just by googling; I happened to know about this article and knew that it contained just what the OP seemed to be (CTD)

Comment: (CTD) asking for, but that might well not have been obvious from a page of Google search results.

Comment: At the very least this answer would benefit from a citation instead of simply "this" in the hyperlink text.