# Newtonian Mechanics in first-order logic

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, mathematical-physics

I asked a similar question before, but it did not give the answer I was looking for, so I will clarify what I actually want in this question. H. Andreka created a formal first-order logic theory that was meant to axiomatize special relativity. I very much enjoyed reading his paper and other papers that axiomatized special relativity. However, I have yet to find a similar text for Newtonian mechanics. What I am looking for is a paper or papers that give a formal first-order theory that axiomatize Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: Link to similar question?

Comment: Related: [Is there a text that axiomatizes general relativity in first-order logic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565796/9290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might run into problems, because Newton used nonstandard analysis in his *Principia*. There have been endeavours to formalize this, see, e.g.,:

- Jacques Fleuriot, [*A Combination of Geometry Theorem Proving and Nonstandard Analysis with Application to Newton’s Principia*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1852334665); PhD thesis published as a book.
- Jacques D. Fleuriot and Lawrence C. Paulson, [A Combination of Nonstandard Analysis and Geometry Theorem Proving, with Application to Newton’s Principia](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Elp15/papers/Isabelle/fleuriot-princip-CADE.pdf)
- Lars Werne, [Mechanising Newtonian Mechanics in Isabelle](https://project-archive.inf.ed.ac.uk/ug4/20223088/ug4_proj.pdf)

**Addendum.** There are two types of problems you'll encounter.

The first, more serious, is when Newton tries to solve the Kepler problem, he multiplies an infinity by an infinitesimal and asserts it is infinitesimal. But this isn't true, according to nonstandard analysis, which requires fixing Newton's work. Fleuriot did this in his thesis (among other things).

The second, less serious, problem is interpreting infinitesimals. For a review of "What they actually meant", see:

- Jacques Bair, *et al.*, "Interpreting the infinitesimal mathematics of Leibniz and Euler" https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00455

Comment: What problem would this cause?

Comment: @WillO Well, the problem is how to interpret what Newton "really meant" when worked with infinities and infinitesimals, whether it corresponds with what Nonstandard Analysis formalizes, or whether there is some quirky idiosyncracy to Newton's terminology. This has been argued to death with, e.g., Euler's use of the Binomial series involving infinitesimals and infinities, whether it corresponds to what NSA's infinities and infinitesimals, and so on.

Comment: @WillO for a literature review of the problem of interpreting infinitesimals, see [arXiv:1605.00455](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00455)

Comment: When I say Newtonian mechanics, I mean classical mechanics, which has to do with position, velocity, acceleration, point particles, mass, etc.

Comment: @user107952 Yeah, even formalizing calculus is tedious without nonstandard analysis, which lends itself to formalizing Newton's _Principia_ as opposed to, say, Euler's _Mechanica_ (or other forms of Newtonian mechanics). Trying to formalize analytical mechanics is even harder, since you need to formalize differential geometry (which is notoriously difficult to do adequately).

Comment: @user107952 Lars Werne's thesis linked is almost certainly what you're asking for.